# Flutter How to save and show List<Object> to SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want to save and read a list of elements called coursesfav.

I have the following code where I made the map of the class, but I don't know how to save the elements of the string map inside a List one by one, going through the list and then displaying all the elements in a ListView.

This is what I have

```
//my class

    class curso {
      final String title;
      final String entidad;
      final String categoria;
      final String emision;
      final String imgcourse;
      final String urlcourse;
      final String idioma;
      final String duracion;
      final String description;
    
      curso({
        required this.title,
        required this.entidad,
        required this.categoria,
        required this.emision,
        required this.imgcourse,
        required this.urlcourse,
        required this.idioma,
        required this.duracion,
        required this.description,
      });
    
      Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
        return {
          'title': title,
          'entidad': entidad,
          'categoria': categoria,
          'emision': emision,
          'imgcourse': imgcourse,
          'urlcourse': urlcourse,
          'idioma': idioma,
          'duracion': duracion,
          'description': description,
        };
      }
    
      curso.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> res)
          : title = res["title"],
            entidad = res["entidad"],
            categoria = res["categoria"],
            emision = res["emision"],
            imgcourse = res["imgcourse"],
            urlcourse = res["urlcourse"],
            idioma = res["idioma"],
            duracion = res["duracion"],
            description = res["description"];
    
      @override
      String toString() {
        return 'curso{title: $title, entidad: $entidad, categoria: $categoria, emision: $emision, imgcourse: $imgcourse, urlcourse: $urlcourse, idioma: $idioma, duracion: $duracion, description: $description}';
      }
    }
```

this is how i call

```
  void saveCourseFavSP(String title,String entidad,String categoria,String emision,String imgcourse,String urlcourse,String idioma,String duracion,String description) async {
    
   //init sharedpreferences
    SharedPreferences cursosFav = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    //object variable to load the info
    final testCursoFav = curso(
        title: title,
        entidad: entidad,
        categoria: categoria,
        emision: emision,
        imgcourse: imgcourse,
        urlcourse: urlcourse,
        idioma: idioma,
        duracion: duracion,
        description: description);

    String json = jsonEncode(testCursoFav);
    print("generating json $json");
    
    //sending all items object to sharedPreferences
    cursosFav.setString('coursesFavorites', json);

   //here i want to insert String to List<Strin>
   //sending String to something like .upperCase 
   //but i dont know how to parse and how to read 

  List<String> lista = jsonDecode(json);

  }

  loadDataCursosFavSP() async {
    SharedPreferences cursosFav = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    String? json = cursosFav.getString("coursesFavorites");
    print("datos de curso favorito cargados:\n $json");

    if (json == null) {
      print("Items doesn't exist");
    } else {
      Map<String, dynamic> map = jsonDecode(json);

      final cursofav = curso.fromMap(map);

      print(
        "titulo fav: ${cursofav.title}, ${cursofav.entidad},${cursofav.emision},");
    }
  }

  clearDataCursosFavSP() async {
    SharedPreferences cursosFav = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    cursosFav.clear();
    print("ALL ITEMS LIST ARE DELETED");
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not that clear but I assume you want to store the list in shared prefs for that you have to convert your list to JSON and then store the encoded JSON to shared prefs.

```
var json = jsonEncode(yourlist.map((e) => e. toMap()).toList());

cursosFav.setString('coursesFavorites', json);
```